# Django error for psycopg2 ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: django, heroku, importerror

Hi I am getting this error while I am trying to run syncdb in my virtual environment.

If I copy psycopg2 folder to my project folder (where I have my `manage.py` and `settings.py`) then this error disappears. But I still get this error when the code is pushed to heroku.

I have referred to many online materials but wasn't very lucky.

```
File "c:\Users\mayayadav\anteus\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.4.5-py2.7-wi
  n32.egg\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. (venv)
```

Comment: Have you installed the PostgreSQL client library?

Comment: Yes I did, i have installed psycopg from http://initd.org/psycopg/ and did an "easy_install psycopg2". Its still not working, is there any other lib i should be using ?

Comment: The PostgreSQL client library, which the DB-API adapter (which you have installed) uses to talk to the database server.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem on `Windows`, The way i get it working was to install `psycopg2` from:

http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

And doing it this way it's recomended here http://initd.org/psycopg/install/

Comment: Note that the particularly important part of this for VirtualEnv's can be found below the Windows installer download:

    Do not double-click the package to run. Instead, use easy_install to execute the .exe from within your activated virtualenvironment.

Comment: be sure to choose the 32 bit version or he 64 bit version  according to your system on the stickpeople website

Answer (score 12):

In the case, where the install binaries are not up to date (as it happened today: latest Python is 3.4 and PostgresSQL - 9.3, while latest avaiable are 3.3 and 9.2.6 respectively), it is enough to add the PostgresSQL binary path (e.g. `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin`) to the path variable.

Note: you need to restart your command line to get it working.

Comment: This tip worked for me. I'm on Windows 8 64 bits Brazilian Portuguese, Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 64-bit, Postgres 9.3 with Postgis enabled. I installed both psycopg2 and ppygis with `pip install`.

Comment: I updated windows path to include Postgres bin folder. But had to restart command line to get it working was what I needed!

Answer (score 6):

**2019 Update**

I encountered the same issue with Python 3.8 and `psycopg2` 2.8.3 and 2.8.4. Apparently `psycopg2` doesn't work with Python 3.8 yet (understandably, since 3.8 released very recently). The fix for me was to go back to using Python 3.7.

Comment: I ran pip install psycopg2-binary and it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

It's so old problem... I ran into a problem with PyCharm and virtualenv, PyCharm have problem with pip install psycopg2. I copied _psycopg.cp38-win_amd64.pyd from global python to \venv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2. And all done.